# What is the meaning of <rayCount>, <rangeCount> and <laserCount> for laser sensor XML?

Tags: xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using simulating a laser sensor. However, I have some doubts about the meaning of some tags in the xml description. Even the ROS [web page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/sensor) do not provide information on this.

The xml description look something like this

```
<gazebo reference="base_scan_link">
            <sensor:ray name="laser">
                <rayCount>683</rayCount>
                <rangeCount>683</rangeCount>
                <laserCount>1</laserCount>
            
                <origin>0.0 0.0 0.0</origin>
                <displayRays>false</displayRays>
            
                <minAngle>-135</minAngle>
                <maxAngle> 135</maxAngle>
            
                <minRange>0.06</minRange>
                <maxRange>4.0</maxRange>
                <resRange>0.001</resRange>
                <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
            
                <controller:gazebo_ros_laser 
name="gazebo_ros_base_scan_link_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
                    <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
                    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                    <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
                    <topicName>base_scan/scan</topicName>
                    <frameName>base_scan_link</frameName>
                    <interface:laser name="gazebo_ros_base_scan_link_iface"/>
                </controller:gazebo_ros_laser>
            </sensor:ray>
        </gazebo>
```

I wish to know what are the function of , , and Gaussian noise.
Can anyone explain what are the meanings of the above mentioned tags? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51025/what-is-the-meaning-of-%3Craycount%3E,-%3Crangecount%3E-and-%3Clasercount%3E-for-laser-sensor-xml?/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-12-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-24**:
Please provide more information.  What web page are you looking at? What xml file are you trying to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page has information on the actual xml structure:
http://answers.ros.org/question/44691/how-to-put-hokuyo-laser-sensor-on-p2os/

As for those meanings, I found some information here on rangecount and raycount:
http://osdir.com/ml/science.robotics.playerstage.gazebo/2008-08/msg00044.html

rangecount is the amount of data to export.  Raycount is the number of rays to simulate in gazebo.  Since these can be computationally expensive, each rangecount will be interpolated to the nearest raycount if raycount < rangecount.  For best sensor simulation, raycount = rangecount.

There's no clear use for lasercount anywhere, other than 1.  I'd assume it's the number of planar lasers, the number of stacked lasers, or the number of returns.

Finally, the Gaussian noise is the amount of simulated noise to add to each reading.  Gazebo supports "noisy" data by adding data in a distribution with that number as the variance.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-27**:
Thank you for the information, they are very helpful.